# Can pilots hear their passengers clapping on touchdown?

Tags: landing, passenger, airliner, pilots, noise

Something that just popped into my head: I've been on a few easyJet and Ryanair flights where a lot of passengers clap and cheer on touchdown. Would the pilots be able to hear this?

Here's an example I found by [searching YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=clapping%20plane&sm=3):

It seems pretty commonplace... but can the pilots hear them? I guess it would be distracting.

Just something I was wondering!

Comment: i can testify that i've heard the 'reverse' happening- the sound of the master warning of the autopilot turning off in the first few rows :)

Comment: It's idiotic. Do I start clapping for my doctor when he's done?

Comment: Yes, but the *question* is "Can pilots hear clapping?"

Comment: I cannot understand how the chatterboxes in that plane even noticed that the plane has landed.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In my 10 years of flying 747s on international flights, there was no way we would know of passenger reactions upon landing unless one of the cabin staff told us, and that was rare.

Comment: Yeah, I would imagine that to be the case in a 747 due to where the cockpit is. I suppose that the answer to this question is really "it depends on the aircraft".

Answer (score 21):

We can in my airplane:

[image: Falcon 50]

Quite frankly, I'm usually a little insulted when it happens.

Were they actually so fearful for their lives and are now so happy to be alive that they need to applaud the heroic pilots?  Sorry, but unless it's a true emergency and we did actually just save their lives, I'm not putting them in a situation where they are actually at risk.  In this case, I was just doing my job.  Do you applaud the waiter or waitress who gets your order right??  :-)

As far as airliners, I'm pretty sure that the pilots can hear you too if everyone is clapping but someone with experience on that should confirm whether or not this is true.

---

Disclaimer:  This isn't the **actual** airplane that I fly, but it is the same kind.  Notice also that we don't have a door to our cockpit so this makes it much easier to hear what is going on in back.

Comment: I don't know, most people thank the bus driver when they get off in the UK :) ...I don't understand it either though!

Comment: @DannyBeckett Thanking is one thing, applauding is another!  :)

Comment: That's a fancy airplane!  Does it always come with a glass of wine :)

Comment: @KORD4me It actually comes with a few bottles of wine along with other liquor!  :-)

Comment: @Lnafziger Haha!  I like the disclaimer.  You had me going tho, thought for sure it was YOUR airplane.  Jealousy was raging!

Comment: @KORD4me Ahh, no I don't own one, but I do fly one just like this!

Comment: I also love the way passengers clap as soon as the wheels touch the tarmac. I'd love to know if the passengers on [this flight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwest_Airlines_Flight_1248) were applauding the pilot as the plane ran off the runway onto a highway.

Comment: I'm most of the owners (with some exceptions) of planes like those don't bother to fly them.

Comment: @Farhan True, but I know that Jimmy Buffet flies his!   :-)

Comment: @Lnafziger Yes, that's why I wrote "with some exceptions". [Larry's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Ellison#Pilot) planes must be like that too.

Comment: I imagine part of the reason people clap is out of respect for pilots who operate large, complex machines ... and make it look easy!

Comment: @Lnafziger, I suspect people usually clap based on the perceived 'smoothness' of the landing. Or maybe if there's been some scary 'event' before (turbulence or a go-round).

Comment: A rock band, for instance, must play really badly not to earn any single applause. I think, all crew is rewarded for a flight as such, stewards including.

Comment: I never clap myself but:

1.  Flying is perceived by some to be a dangerous and unnatural activity, people clap due to relief at still being alive.

2.  Lots of people on Ryanair flights probably only fly a couple of times a year so it's not a regular event and they are likely to be in high spirits as they are going on holiday.

3.  Re spirits, they are likely to have consumed a few of those too.

4.  Ryanair encourage this type of behaviour by playing a fanfare when they arrive "on time" and this is probably perceived by some passengers as being a fanfare to say "hey, we didn't die!".

Comment: Musicians or actors who get applauded are also “just doing their job”.  If I applaud you, it doesn’t mean I thought *you* might fail or have difficulty, it just means you have done something that I find impressive, usually because *I* would find it very difficult.  Isn’t it OK to see flying that way?

Comment: Frankly nowadays a good waiter/waitress _would_ deserve applause just to separate them from their sometimes incompetent colleagues. But that is a different world, instead of applause they get a tip in order to compensate for their mostly mediocre wage...

Comment: Depending where you are, university students often applaud after the end of a good lecture by a professor (probably some clapping for the lecture and some clapping for the end), but not because they thought they were in danger.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Well, a performer's job is to entertain, and that clapping is to give them feedback on how the did....  I suppose one could say that the passengers are giving feedback to the pilots as well, but it doesn't usually happen in other similar situations (busses, taxis, etc.)